# What is usage of the last comma in this code?

Tags: python

```
for x in range(1, 11):
     print repr(x).rjust(2), repr(x*x).rjust(3),
     # Note trailing comma on previous line
     print repr(x*x*x).rjust(4)
```

result:

```
 1   1    1
 2   4    8
 3   9   27
 4  16   64
 5  25  125
 6  36  216
 7  49  343
 8  64  512
 9  81  729
10 100 1000
```

If it is a line continuation symbol, why can the author write Print statement again?

If I remove the Print:

```
for x in range(1, 11):
     print repr(x).rjust(2), repr(x*x).rjust(3),
     # Note trailing comma on previous line
     repr(x*x*x).rjust(4)
```

result:

```
 1   1  2   4  3   9  4  16  5  25  6  36  7  49  8  64  9  81 10 100
```

Obviously the last line is ignore. Why? Is it because it is not a statement?

If I put the last expression back to the second line:

```
for x in range(1, 11):
     print repr(x).rjust(2), repr(x*x).rjust(3), repr(x*x*x).rjust(4)
```

result:

```
 1   1    1
 2   4    8
 3   9   27
 4  16   64
 5  25  125
 6  36  216
 7  49  343
 8  64  512
 9  81  729
10 100 1000
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It stops `print` from printing a newline at the end of the text.

As Dave pointed out, the [documentation in python 2.x](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print) says: …. *"A '\n' character is written at the end, unless the print statement ends with a comma."*

**UPDATE:**

The [documentation of python 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) states that `print()` is a function that accepts the keyword argument `end` which defaults to a newline, `\n`.

Comment: Documentation:  http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-print_stmt.  "A '\n' character is written at the end, unless the print statement ends with a comma."

Comment: I understand now.....by the way does python okay with an single expression in a single line like my 2nd example? Does it ignore the expression?

Comment: An expression is a valid statement. If it were not, you wouldn't be able to just call functions without extra syntax.

Answer (score 3):

A comma at the end of a print statement prevents a newline character from being appended to the string.  (See http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement)

In your tweaked code:

```
for x in range(1, 11):
    print repr(x).rjust(2), repr(x*x).rjust(3),
    # Note trailing comma on previous line
    repr(x*x*x).rjust(4)
```

the last line simply becomes an unused expression because Python statements are generally separated by line breaks.  If you added a backslash (\) -- the Python line continuation character -- to the end of the line of the print statement and removed the comment, then the `repr(x*x*x).rjust(4)` would be appended to the print statement.

To be more explicit:

```
print repr(x).rjust(2), repr(x*x).rjust(3), repr(x*x*x).rjust(4)
```

and

```
print repr(x).rjust(2), repr(x*x).rjust(3), \
repr(x*x*x).rjust(4)
```

are equivalent, but

```
print repr(x).rjust(2), repr(x*x).rjust(3),
repr(x*x*x).rjust(4)
```

is not.  This oddness of the print statement is one of the things they fixed in Python 3, by making it a function.  (See http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function)